# Picking N Values at Random From Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to have Excel pick N values at random out of a column where the total number of items in the column is greater than N?  I was thinking of just doing `=RANDBETWEEN(0,1)` but this has the potential to give a value >N.  I'm sure there's probably a simple way to do this that I'm missing.  Thanks.

Comment: what's the purpose?

Comment: You raised the point of the item count being >N, which implies that you might want selections "without replacement" (a pick can be selected only once).  Each RANDBETWEEN result is independent, so it could randomly select the same item more than once (likely if N is high).  You would need to add another "layer" to ensure unique selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I could think of. Say the list of values are listed in column "A" then do this computation in cell B1`=RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A:A))`.
Use the index formula as `=INDEX(A:A,B1)`.
This will return the randomly chosen value from the list in column A
P.S If you like you can also concatenate the two functions as `=INDEX(M:M,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A:A)))`